# SyntaxWalker Visitor doesn't visit Methods

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, microsoft.codeanalysis

I got this walker

```
internal class MyWalker : CSharpSyntaxWalker
{
            public int MethodCount { get; private set; }

    public MyWalker() : base(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SyntaxWalkerDepth.Trivia)
    { }

    public override void VisitMethodDeclaration(MethodDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
         MyMethodCount ++;
    }

    public override void VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        Class++;
        Complexity++;
    }
}
```

I call the walker with this code

```
    var code = @"
    public class foo
    {
        public void MyMethod()
        {

        }
    }
";

  SyntaxTree node = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source);
  var root = node.GetRoot();

  var walker = new MyWalker();
  walker.Visit(root);
```

but the visit MethodDeclaration is never called.

To get sure I compared with the SyntaxTree Analyzer I can see that roslyn should recognize it as Method declaration.
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: its only a wraper of the existing I change the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it. I didn't have the base call in the visit class method. so just a bug of mine

so it should be

```cs
public override void VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
{
    [...]
    base.VisitClassDeclaration(node); // this was missing
}
```